# Android Layout: width half of parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a very simple layout that I can't make it looks like I want. It's a LinearLayout with a button and a Switch. I want them to show one above the other, but I want their width to be the half of the parent layout.

```
|--LinearLayout---------|
|                       |
| -----------           |
||   Switch  |          |
| -----------           |
| -----------           |
||   button  |          |
| -----------           |
 ------------------------
```

I've been looking at other similar answer in SO but I couldn't find a solution that works for me. This is what I've tried so far:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/remember_me_switch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/remember" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/share_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="loginOnclick"
        android:text="@string/login_button_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

With this, the button and the switch take all the space of the parent instead of take only the half.
I've tried with `android:layout_width = 0dp` in the children but it makes they disappear.

Any help, please?

Comment: `layout_weight` is only applied to the dimension specified with `orientation`. That is, weight applies to height in vertical and width in horizontal linear layouts.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

One possible way is to have a master horizontal LinearLayout that splits the width to 2, and inside it have the vertical layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/remember_me_switch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/remember" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/share_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="loginOnclick"
                android:text="@string/login_button_text" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Right side spacer -->
        <View
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="1dp"
           android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, this work for me. The Spacer view made the trick. I will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 32):

The trick is to use **0dp** for the size you want manage via **layout_weight**!
Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/remember_me_switch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/remember" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="loginOnclick"
            android:text="@string/login_button_text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:

1. Use **android:weightSum="2"** in your horizontal parent layout
2. Use **android:layout_weight="1"** and **android:layout_width="0dp"** in your children layouts.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, however, a nice explanation would make it better.

Comment: Looks like the exact same solution as the already accepted answer, only minus the code and ~7.5 years late. Am I missing something?

Comment: this worked for me in 2022!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/remember_me_switch"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/remember" />

               <View 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/share_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="loginOnclick"
                    android:text="@string/login_button_text" />

               <View 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
             </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
int buttonWidth = width/2;
```

set this `buttonWidth` to your button like `button.setWidth(buttonWidth);`

Answer (score 1):

```
int params = linearLayout.getWidth()/2;

ViewGroup.LayoutParams( params, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!